# How does Jgroup on UDP become reliable?

Tags: udp, jgroups

In my mind, UDP is fast but not reliable, and in a lot of places jgroup is based on UDP, is that reliable? I saw a lot of places use jgroup to transfer caching information. Does jgroup have to use TCP to make transition reliable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JGroups provides components to implement reliability above UDP, see here for some details,

http://www.jgroups.org/manual/html_single/index.html#d0e5392